# Is there AUC for neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, auc

I am confused about how to calculate AUC for neural network with a softmax classifier.

For example, I know that for SVM, we can change the threshold value and determine the AUC. WHat about in neural network with a softmax classifier?

Answer (score 5):

Sure. The output of a softmax classifier is a probability for each class. You can order the test instances by their probabilities and then compute false and true positive rates as you choose different probability cutoffs, exactly the same way as you would for the SVM decision function value.

Comment: Basically, I just need to varies the probability cut-off?

Comment: Yep, exactly. It's exactly the same as an SVM threshold, just in $[0,1]$ instead of all of $\mathbb{R}$.